# Change $content_width based on screen size (functions.php)

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I've got a WordPress install where I'm trying to change this content_width code:

```
if( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 290;
```

in my functions.php file based on the users screen size. I've tried using CSS media queries, but for our particular use-case, I need to be able to change this in the functions.php file based on the users screen size.

Ideally 1080 for Desktop, 720 for tables, and 290 for mobile.

Any ideas?

Comment: PHP is executed **before** you have access to the user's screen size. Some mobile phone browsers are sending the size in their User-Agent string, but that's not very reliable. Besides that, it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of `$content_width` is not to be responsive, there is just nothing you can do to it on wordpress side that will change that. For example it is the width that youtube videos will get when they are embedded and the canculation is done only once and will not be redone again unless you clear the relevant cache.

In general you should avoid any client properties detection on server side (what happens if the window size is changed, something that can happen even on surface and ipad), but if you have a good reason for that, you should filter  the content before outputting it to adjust relevant sizes.

Comment: Thanks Mark, we are using the JetPack Plugin Tiled Gallery inside of tabs and on mobile devices it's not adjusting to the content width. So it seems the fix is to adjust that content width based on mobile devices as no CSS seems to fix the issue (I've tried). 

I'm wondering if a solution like this could work…to add this code:
[link](http://pastie.org/10726967) Which will add the browser class to the body, then use a solution similar to this to target the browser class: [link](http://genesissnippets.com/content_width-variable/) I'm not sure what the code would be. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with jetpack, but you should ask about specifics at their support. but in general if all you need to do is insert a device based class on the body element you can easily do it with JS, it is no different then any other elements in this regard. You might pace the JS right after the body element is being output, and use "bare" dom API for it to avoid visual flicker/reflow that might happen when you do such things after the page finished loading (the way that most JS is being done). hmmm google search don't seem to have anything relevant, but it should not be hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, if the screen width is less than 600 pixels, the content width is set to 300 pixels for small screens. You can adjust this value based on your design requirements

```
function dynamic_content_width_script() {
    echo '<script>
        var screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
        var contentWidth = ' . width_calculation() . ';

        if (screenWidth < 600) {
            contentWidth = 300; // Set your desired content width for small screens
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.body.style.maxWidth = contentWidth + "px";
        });

        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            screenWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
            contentWidth = ' . width_calculation() . ';

            if (screenWidth < 600) {
                contentWidth = 300; // Set your desired content width for small screens
            }

            document.body.style.maxWidth = contentWidth + "px";
        });
    </script>';
}


function width_calculation() {
    // Implement your dynamic content width calculation logic here
    // Example: return some_value_based_on_conditions();
    return 800; // Default content width
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'dynamic_content_width_script');
```

script calculates the screen width and adjusts the maxWidth property of the body element accordingly